# get_instance() is returning null in Codeigniter 2

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, model

I need to load my models without `$this->load->model`. I have to load it like this:

```
$modelName = new ModelName();//from a controller

class ModelName{
  public function __construct(){
        $CI =&get_instance();
        var_dump($CI);//null
  }
}
```

It is working fine, but the `$CI =&get_instance();` is actually null. Any idea why?

**Edit 1**
If I am trying the get_instance from a regular Controler, it is working (also from the helper).
I am loading the model with require_once

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you try it the line before `$modelName = new ModelName();`, in the controller? Just a shot in the dark, I'm not sure why this would happen. How about a CI constant (like `CI_VERSION` or `APPPATH`) from the model, is that accessible? To others: `get_instance()` is a global Codeigniter function that returns the Controller/Codeigniter object.

Comment: get_instance is a global function or a class function? If it is a class function, you call it self::get_instance(). Still, I don't see the model extending any other class that would containt the get_instance method.

Comment: Is this model actually being called from the controller in your test case or are you calling it from somewhere else?  How are you loading the model.  Are you using your own custom autoload function? More details please.

Comment: Yes, but where are you loading the model from with require_once()?  I doubt that anyone will be able to help you solve your problem without all of the relevant code.

Comment: Where are your models? in libraries? `$this->load->library('ModelName')` work?

Comment: I'm new with CodeIgniter, but don't you need `extends CI_Model` to have access to `get_instance()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try extending CI_Model.

```
class ModelName extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct(){
        $CI =&get_instance();
        var_dump($CI);
    }
}
```